# Using .htaccess and apache mod_rewrite for flexible and dynamic Redirection Rules?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dynamic, url-rewriting

I want to use .htaccess and the apache modul mod_rewrite to provide flexible and dynamic 
url-processing.

For Example: I have maximal 4 variables i want to deliver to a php-script via mod-rewrite.

```
http://www.myfantasticsite.com/Var1/Var2/Var3/Var4
```

The realization of this is not very complicated:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
```

But here is the Problem: I want a dynamic and flexible url processing. This means that 
Variable 2(Var2), Variable 3(Var3) and Variable 4(Var4) are optional. The Redirection should work also with this kind of urls:

```
http://www.myfantasticsite.com/Var1/Var2/Var3
http://www.myfantasticsite.com/Var1/Var2
http://www.myfantasticsite.com/Var1
```

But i by myself have not found a way to allow such flexible processing. All my tries end up with an internal server error.

Comment: I was thinking... you could just use [`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Yes `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would be an option but i would prefer to solve this whole thing explicit and only with mod_rewrite engine in .htaccess so that php dont even now that mod_rewrite was used.

Answer (score 0):

make the other url-parts optional by using an `?`.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?$ /index.php?var1=$1&var2=$3&var3=$5&var4=$7 [L]
```